# Add object to database with username

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting a simple object from a form in a MVC4 application

`portfolio = {code: xxxxx, quantity: -10}`

I need to add the Username to the database when I do this insert which I already know I can get from the HTTPContext.

What would be the best way to include this in the below code. I know I will need to change the object I am adding but what is the right way to do this?

```
   public ActionResult Add(Portfolio portfolio)
        {
            var ctx = new MarginEntities();
            ctx.Portfolios.Add(portfolio);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the `Portfolio` class to include the necessary property:

```
class Portfolio
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

When the request comes from client, fields `Code` and `Quantity` are initialized, and `Username` is set to its default value, which is null. So simply initialize it before submitting to DB:

```
public ActionResult Add(Portfolio portfolio)
{
    portfolio.Username = Session["Username"]; // or however the username is stored

    var ctx = new MarginEntities();
    ctx.Portfolios.Add(portfolio);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the User object, I take it all users are first authenticated?

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Your Portfolio object could then either have a string for the username or you could use a FK to the 'users' table, and get this ID by passing in the Name property from above.

You could then have either:

```
class Portfolio
{
    ...    
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

If you take this approach, then you would just pass the Portfolio object with the new Username property set.

or

```
class Portfolio
{
    ...    
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

if you take this approach then you would need to request the UserId from EF context and then populate the Portfolio object with the returned UserId